# NSString Append EXC_BAD_ACCESS Url Connection

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, append, nsurlconnection

I am new to Objective-C however I am slowly making progress. All I would like to do is append a new string to a current string. I need to do this for my `NSURLConnection` so that I can put all the data into one string. I currently have something like this, however it does work and I don't fully understand why and what I need to do to fix it.

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
html = [htmlTemp stringByAppendingString:temp];
htmlTemp = html;
```

Thanks For any help I am sure its something to do with the memory however I don't fully understand that either.

Comment: `it does work` or `it does not work`?

Comment: if it ain't broke, don't fix it

Comment: post some more code of request URl and connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringByAppendingString` is a convenience method that does not start with "new" or contains "alloc" or "copy", the returned string will be `autoreleased` most likely in the next run cycle, which is why when you try to read it again from html, it has already been released. To fix this you can send a `copy` message like this:

```
htmlTemp = [html copy];
```

I would recommend making htmlTemp a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *htmlTemp;
```

This way when you assign a new value to it, using the setter, the old value will get released, before pointing to the new value that way you can do:

```
self.htmlTemp = [htmlTemp stringByAppendingString:temp];
```

Comment: Warning, that if htmlTemp is null already, the results of `-stringByAppendingString:` will also always be null.